# Mustache.js duplicating templaer

Tags: mustache

I have the following code in my app. The first time the click event is fired template is added to the page as expected.

However the second time two copies of the template are added, the third time three are added etc. So after three clicks I actually have 6 copies of my template within the DOM.

Even if I set template_view to null after it has been added it continues to happen.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to avoid it?

```
template_path = "/templates/";
var template_html;  

$.get(template_path+"template.html", function(template) {
    template_html = template;
});     


$('#test_add').click(function(){
    var template_data = {name:'whatever'};  
    template_view = Mustache.to_html(template_html, template_data); 
    $(body).append(template_view);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why this was happening. Initially though my template was a static html file with no mustache tags in it. Having added a few and passing an array to loop through it's now no longer duplicating the template each time the function is called